# Erro ao Abrir um Projeto Maven

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, spring-mvc

[image: Maven Project Builder]

[image: 2]

Toda vez que tento importar algum projeto maven/Spring me dá esse erro, algum erro na build 3.0.1. Alguém sabe o que pode ser?

Eu estou utilizando um MacBook Pro (versão 10.13.6 (17G65)) macOS High Sierra.

Comment: Parece que o diretório `testE` já existe

Comment: Nao e isso, ja criei e recriei diversas vezes, uns falam que o problema e no jdk

Answer (score 0):

Não é uma solução, mas uma alternativa:

Cria um Java Project normal, depois lá no Package/Project Explorer, clica com o direito no projeto, vai em Configure -> Convert to Maven Project.